Не работает вывод в терминал vsc
Всем доброго времени суток. Пытался настроить vsc и дебаг кода на маке(с М процессором), но в итоге в терминал не выводится результат программы, и не работает ввод в терминале, после нажатия любой клавиши закрывается, даже если в коде был cin. ниже прикреплю tasks и json. Спасибо заранее!
{"tasks"
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++17",
            "-stdlib=libc++",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
]

}
{"launch"
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
    }
]

}
